# Jenkins Global Script and Jenkins Global Vars -- referencing one from the other

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries

I am refactoring a Jenkins shared library that used classes, e.g.

```
workflow = new myWorkflow( def script ) {
    this.script = script
```

and replacing with shared (script) libraries in the /vars directory:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
# file: /vars/myFunc.groovy
doSomething() {
    myFlow = new myWorkflow(this)
}
```

Scripts in the /vars directory are very useful and lightweight compared to classes. Your code is very very FP. Here is my issue, the code I transition from has a reference to the Jenkinsfile script, e.g.
`script.sh "ls -la"` but the global functions don't know their reference, they don't know their owner, the script they are running in, being called from. This makes it impossible to call some of the existing objects. In the above example, "this" is myFunc, not Jenkinsfile this.

Is there a `this.owner` or `this.parent` ?